# Swift is not printing or displaying name in App from a weather API?

Tags: swift, xcode

```
if let jsonObj = jsonObj as? [String: Any],

let weatherDictionary = jsonObj["weather"] as? [String: Any],

let weather = weatherDictionary["description", default: "clear sky"] as? 
NSDictionary {

                            print("weather")

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.conditionsLabel.text = "\(weather)"
                        }
                    }

// to display weather conditions in "name" from Open Weather

"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}]

//No errors, but code is not printing or displaying in App.
```

Comment: I want to be able to pull from the "weather" dictionary a single item to display in my App, ie Description : "clear sky" I want that single object "clear sky" to display with a conditionsLabel. I can do this if there is a value, but need helps to write the code for a single name/object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to help with your exact question unless you can provide some more code for context. However,

You might try using the built-in decoding that comes with Swift 4. Check it out [here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) Basically, you make a class that models the response object, like this:

```
struct Weather: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var main: String
    var description: String
    var icon: String
}
```

Then decode it like so:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let weather = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: jsonObj)
```

And it magically decodes into the data you need! Let me know if that doesn't work, and comment if you have more code context for your problem that I can help with.

Comment: if let jsonObj = jsonObj as? [String: Any],
                        let weatherDictionary = jsonObj["weather"] as? [String: Any],
                        let weather = weatherDictionary["description", default: "clear sky"] as? NSDictionary {
                        
                            print("weather")
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.conditionsLabel.text = "\(weather)"
                        }
                    }

Comment: does that help Aaron?

Comment: I used this to pull a "value" and it works great...but to pull a name from the library is not the same...

Comment: if let mainDictionary = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "main") as? NSDictionary {
                        if let temperature = mainDictionary.value(forKey: "temp"){
                        
                          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.weatherLabel.text = "Temperature: \(temperature)°C"
                                
                           
                            }
                        }

Comment: let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) {

Comment: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void'

Answer (score 0):

I put the complete demo here to show how to send a HTTP request and parse the JSON response.

Note, Configure ATS if you use HTTP request, rather than HTTPS request.

[image]

- The demo URL is "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22".
- The JSON format is as below, and the demo shows how to get the city name.

`{
  cod: "200",
  message: 0.0032,
  cnt: 36,
  list: [...],
  city: {
    id: 6940463,
    name: "Altstadt",
    coord: {
      lat: 48.137,
      lon: 11.5752
    },
    country: "none"
  }
}`

- The complete demo is as below. It shows how to use `URLSessionDataTask` and `JSONSerialization`.

  ```
  class WeatherManager {
    static func sendRequest() {
      guard let url = URL(string: "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22") else {
        return
      }
      // init dataTask
      let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        let name = WeatherManager.cityName(fromWeatherData: data)
        print(name ?? "")
      }
      // send the request
      dataTask.resume()
    }

    private static func cityName(fromWeatherData data: Data?) -> String? {
      guard let data = data else {
        print("data is nil")
        return nil
      }

      do {
        // convert Data to JSON object
        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        print(jsonObject)
        if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: Any],
          let cityDic = jsonObject["city"] as? [String: Any],
          let name = cityDic["name"] as? String {
          return name
        } else {
          return nil
        }
      } catch {
        print("failed to get json object")
        return nil
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Steven, no errors, but still not printing/or displaying in my Label on my app the weather "description" from the weatherDictionary. Any ideas how to further the code to make it work?

Comment: Hi Rich. How do you get the initial jsonObj? The response from Weather API is a `Data` object, and do you convert it to JSON object? Check out [Swift: Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) to know more about it.

Comment: Hi Steven, it keeps tell me the NSDictionary has no member "Data" is does have "Value" which I have no problem getting.

Comment: Rich, I updated my answer to show the complete HTTP request & JSON parse demo. Hope it help.

Comment: Which "return nil" and which kind of error? I don't get any errors in my Xcode 9.2 (9C40b).